# Counter-increment with wrapping divs

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I want to use a counter-increment on ordered lists. I want each `ol` to continue on the previous count.

It works when I don't have separate wrapping divs around the `ol`s.  Note that it works for the second `ol` which is within the same wrapping div, but it stops working for the next two `ol`s which has a separate wrapping div:

http://jsfiddle.net/graphic_dev/Lsn49t16/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ol class="split start">
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>Dolor</li>
    </ol>

    <ol class="split">
      <li>Sit</li>
      <li>Amet</li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- It stops working here -->
    <ol class="split">
      <li>Consectetur</li>
      <li>Adipiscing </li>
    </ol>

    <ol class="split">
      <li>Elit</li>
      <li>Sed</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.start {
    counter-reset: mycounter;
}

.split {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.split li:before {
    counter-increment: mycounter;
    content: counter(mycounter, upper-alpha);
}
```

How do I get it continuing the count for each `ol`? I need the wrapping divs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#scope)

> The scope of a counter starts at the first element in the document that has a 'counter-reset' for that counter and includes the element's descendants and its following siblings with their descendants.

So, you need to call the `counter-reset` on the wrapping element of your lists, or the first `<div class="wrapper">`.

[Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsn49t16/3/) which initialize the `mycounter` on `body` as an example.

And also from the spec

> If 'counter-increment' or 'content' on an element or pseudo-element refers to a counter that is not in the scope of any 'counter-reset', implementations should behave as though a 'counter-reset' had reset the counter to 0 on that element or pseudo-element.

so the list item in the second `div` actually initialized a counter for each of the items.